# Compare two IEnumerable<> Collection data

Tags: c#

I have two IEnumerable data collections that I would like to compare and get first collection values selected.

Here is what I am trying to do.

ClassA

Column|IsMatched

```
----
1
2
2 
2
3
4
5
```

### ClassB

Column

```
1  
2 
7
3
5
2
```

After comparison, I would like to get following.

ClassA

### Column|IsMatched

```
1  true
2  true
2  true  
2  false
3  true
6  false 
5  true
4  false
```

Second collection may be in any order.

Any help to sort this issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Explain it better please. You should also show what you have tried unsuccesfully.

Comment: So you have two `IEnumerables<int>` or two `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`? You specify 'ClassA' and 'ClassB', but there is no definition of the field names (unless 'column' and 'IsMatched' are properties of the class).

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want us to write it for you?

Comment: Where does the value of 6 in the output come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
var workingBag = new List<int>(secondCollection);
var results = firstCollection.Select(i => new ClassA(i, workingBag.Remove(i));
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but it's a mystery to me how you know what OP wants. Too many unknown elements.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The question isn't *that* bad, really.  The example makes the output pretty clear, and this matches their expected output...

Comment: I still don't understand what OP is trying to do. Maybe you could explain it us.

Comment: @TimSchmelter He's trying to match all of the items in the first collection with the second, processing in order.  You can't use a set, because there are duplicates. For example, he has 3 values of "2" in c1, and only 2 values of "2" in c2, so it matches to true, true, false...

Comment: @TimSchmelter Though, to be honest, I may be off, since I don't know where the `6` comes from ;)

Comment: Thanks Reed. Got it working with a slight change in your code.<code>var results = firstCollection.Select(i => new ClassA(i, workingBag.Remove(workingBag.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.col==i.col)));</code>

Comment: @Reed, 6 shouldn't have been there. Sorry for not explain the question properly. requirement was matching first collection with the second one.

I have accepted your answer. ta